# How can I share the entire contents from one Google Drive account as a folder in another user's Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

For example, I have a Google Drive account for my business and a Google Drive account for myself.

Some of the folders in both accounts have the same names (e.g., accounts, pics, documents etc.), which can be confusing.

What I would like to do is have the entire contents of my business account available via a synced folder in my personal account (e.g., just called 'my business').

Is it possible to do this and if so, how do I do it?

Comment: Related: [How to share Entire Google Drive—right click menu with “share” option on “My Drive” not available](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/48439/60818)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way would be to make a top level folder called "Business" in your business account, and a "Personal" folder at the top level in your personal account

Then place ALL your business folders below "Business" in your business account and similar in your personal account.

Google Drive doesn't really see each folder as separate in that way.  Even if a friend of yours shares an "Account" folder with you, and you already have 2 "Account" folders, it won't nest that any differently.

I personally have "email@address.com" as my top level in my different Google Apps accounts, and I bookmark that page (where I have browsed into that folder) in my toolbar. This seems to be the best solution for me, and at a glance it is very obvious which folder I want.

Comment: That's pretty much the 'fix' that I opted to use. Not ideal, but better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder, put everything in it, share it with the other account. You can then change the "owner" in the share settings for that folder, and move the contents out of the folder in the new account.

Comment: This is only possible if both accounts belongs to the same "domain" (both accounts are @gmail.com or both belongs to the same Google Workspace organization)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the setting of your business account to include sharing with your personal account.
You can't have two Google Drive Folders on one computer even if the users login to the computer through login accounts and they download their own Google Drive App.  This will cause massive problems.
At least that is what Google says for Mac users.  Not sure if it is the same for PC's.

Comment: Step by step please.