# How can I share an entire Google Drive account's contents as a folder in another account's Drive?

Tags: google-drive, file-sharing

I have multiple Google Accounts: one personal, one for a business I run, another at a non-profit I work at. Since I can only sign into Drive as one user for the purposes of the desktop syncing app (on Mac), I want to share the contents of the latter two accounts with my personal account such that they appear as folders there. (I can then add them to My Drive and get access to them via Finder.)

This is a duplicate of [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43719/how-can-i-share-an-entire-google-drive-accounts-contents-as-a-folder-in-another). However, that question has not been fully answered. There is a suggestion that it is possible to change a setting in order to make this happen, however there is no description of how to find that setting. Other sources online (e.g. in response to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372919/is-it-possible-to-share-an-entire-google-drive-for-another-user)) have suggested sharing every single file and folder individually (perhaps by using the API to automate the process), however this is no use since I will be adding new files all the time. For now my solution is to put everything within a folder (i.e. no files or other folders at root level) and then share that folder. However, this makes the experience of using the web version of Drive rather frustrating, since I need to click down into that dummy folder every time I go to Drive.

Comment: Could you link to those other sources so we can see what they recommend?

Comment: @batpigandme: Of course. The first one (which I already included) is: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/43719/how-can-i-share-an-entire-google-drive-accounts-contents-as-a-folder-in-another. The second one is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372919/is-it-possible-to-share-an-entire-google-drive-for-another-user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you describe is the best solution.

I personally have "email@address.com" as my top level in my different Google Apps accounts, and I *bookmark that page* (where I have browsed into that folder) in my toolbar.

This seems to be the best solution for me, and at a glance it is very obvious which folder I want in my other drives.

On a day to day basis, just clicking on that bookmark is enough to get me into the folder that I treat as "root"

You can also use a URL shortener to create links like blah.blah/persdrive that you can then use on public/shared computers where you don't have your bookmarks. I do that for my Google Apps for domains to avoid typing the whole google.com/a/domain.com every time

Comment: It's still inconvenient when you add new file to a drive - you always need to "reorganize", because every new file gets added to root folder by default.

Answer (score 0):

You have "My Drive" and "Shared with me".  You don't have to add the root folder to your drive, just the next level up.  The great thing about the web app is that you can select all ;)

Comment: Just so I'm sure I know what you're suggesting: let's say account A is the 'master' one logged into in the desktop syncing app. Account B is one of the others, the entire contents of which I want included in the desktop sync. Are you suggesting, in the web interface, logging into account B, selecting all the items, sharing with account A, then logging into account A, going to Shared with me, and dragging all the newly shared items into My Drive? The problem with that is you have to repeat whenever anything new is added at root level to account B.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative approach would be to switch to a desktop syncing client that supports multiple accounts simultaneously. [Insync](https://www.insynchq.com/) is one good example, another possibility would be software running on an NAS device (e.g. [Cloud Sync](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/5.2/cloud_services) on a Synology Disk Station).