# How to share Entire Google Drive—right click menu with “share” option on “My Drive” not available

Tags: google-drive, sharing, url

I can right click a folder

[image: Can right click a folder]

But not the entire drive

[image: but not the entire drive]

**Background**
For my employer, I want to share my entire Google Drive space provided by them. I want to be able to have a direct URL to my whole drive in my email footer. This is so that they can always access my work if I am unavailable.

Research so far:
Already looked for solutions—most say “share the folders” you want to share, but I want everything to be shared. The workaround would be to create a master folder and put everything in that and share it, but I'd prefer the top level “root” of the drive to be shared and specifically I want *a direct URL of the whole drive* to share to people.

Comment: `The workaround would be to create a master folder and put everything in that and share it` - Whats wrong with that approach?

Comment: +1 Yes I am doing that. Nothing wrong with it. But it was a workaround alternative to my original problem. But on reflection, perhaps not being able to share the entire drive is by design.

Comment: Share the link.

Comment: Related: [How can I share the entire contents from one Google Drive account as a folder in another user's Google Drive?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/43719/60818)

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately you can't share your entire Google Drive like you can share a folder. Google doesn't treat Drive that way.

Think of your Google Drive storage as a post office. You can give anyone you want access to as many of the individual "boxes" inside the post office lobby as necessary, but you can't give anyone access to the entire building.

The workaround you suggested -- with a shared master folder -- is as close as you can come to sharing the entire contents of your Drive account, with the exception of @MilesMichaelson's idea of sharing credentials (which is definitely NOT recommended).

Once you've shared the master folder, you can easily grab the URL by right-clicking on the folder, selecting **Share**, and clicking **Get shareable link** in the upper right corner.

Answer (score 0):

Systools Google Drive Migrator software has been designed to do just that. It is THE solution I think. And it's not so expensive either. Go see it here:
https://www.systoolsgroup.com/google-drive/migration/

Answer (score -2):

Well I guess you could just give the email address and the password to the person you are trying to send it to then you both could just have the same drive

Comment: What a fundamentally bad idea. That gives access to the entire Google account.

Answer (score -4):

Just create the new folder (eg: Public), share that folder as "Public on the web", then move your folders (dev, docs, login, projects) under Public folder

Comment: OP is already aware of that option and is looking for a different way.